# Google Sheets for Developers Sheets API append function appending row to first row of table instead of appending at the end

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const sheets = google.sheets('v4');
var request = {
    spreadsheetId: triggerDoc.parameters.spreadSheetId,
    range: sheetName + "!A:Z",
    insertDataOption: "INSERT_ROWS",
    responseDateTimeRenderOption: "SERIAL_NUMBER",
    responseValueRenderOption: "FORMATTED_VALUE",
    valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
    "includeValuesInResponse": true,
    resource: {
        values: rowsToInsert
    },
    auth: oAuth2Client,
};
sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(request, function (err, response) {
    resp.spreadsheets = true;
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return callback(err);
    }
    // console.log(response);
    return callback();
});
```

I am using the above code to append a set of values into the google sheet, the value is getting appended but instead of appending end, getting added to the first-line because the google sheet is not recognizing the table range correctly.

When I triggered the API from [Developer Tool](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) google sheet recognizing the table and starting to append value to the end of the table.

[image]
Here the value is not appended in the order of API triggered.

Comment: In your situation, in order to correctly replicate your issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue as an image?

Comment: Why `"includeValuesInResponse"` in quotes while the others don't have quotes? It's a valid variable name. Just a spec...

Comment: Unfortunately, when I tested your script for your sample Spreadsheet showing in your image, the values are appended to the next row of the last row. So I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. By the way, in your script, I think that `INSERT_ROW` of `insertDataOption: "INSERT_ROW",` should be `INSERT_ROWS`. So I'm worried that you had miscopied your script for replicating your issue to your question. How about this?

Comment: I understand the issue, but don't know how to solve this. For every value adding first cell in the row is empty so google sheet is not able to find the position of starting of the row. When I added a random value to first column it works.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your sample image. From your updated image, I could replicate your situation. So I proposed a workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tested the spreadsheet of your updated image, I could confirm the same issue with you. In this case, when the column "B" is the number, your issue occurred. When I modified the values of column "B" to the string values, I confirmed that the inputted values could be appended to the last row. So I thought that this might be a bug.

From the above situation, in order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following workaround.

1. Retrieve the last row number using `sheets.spreadsheets.values.get()`.
2. Append the values to last row of the sheet using `sheets.spreadsheets.values.update()`.

When this workaround is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(
  {
    spreadsheetId: triggerDoc.parameters.spreadSheetId,
    range: sheetName + "!A:Z",
    auth: oAuth2Client,
  },
  (err, { data }) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    const row = data.values.length + 1;
    var request = {
      spreadsheetId: triggerDoc.parameters.spreadSheetId,
      range: sheetName + "!A" + row,
      responseDateTimeRenderOption: "SERIAL_NUMBER",
      responseValueRenderOption: "FORMATTED_VALUE",
      valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
      includeValuesInResponse: true,
      resource: {
        values: rowsToInsert,
      },
      auth: oAuth2Client,
    };
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(request, (err, { data }) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
);
```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)